# No handlers matched this URL -- URL points to GWT file

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, gwt-rpc

I get this warning often in my Google App Engine for Java warning console.  It's strange because the URL that it claims isnt handled, is the url generated by GWT (im using GWT client-side).

Heres an example:  /myAppName/62865E45F313D707543A6F093D199127.cache.html

They only happen occasionally, but its enough to make a single visit useless.

Comment: I made some updates to my app and now I'm getting this error every time I try to visit from my domain... however, when i go directly to the appspot link (ie 6.latest.myapp.appspot.com), itll work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure, but it could have to do with browser cacheing (though the *.ClientMod.nocache.js is specifically designed to prevent this). Does clearing your browser's cache or visiting the page in incognito mode help?

Comment: It doesnt seem to.  After I deploy, it will happen without fail the first time I visit the site.  Afterward, it will happen every now and then to me, and to certain users.  It's more prevalent in certain deployments than others... For example, I may deploy right now without any changes in the client-side code and only get 2 or 3 of these in the next 24 hours, but I've gotten over 60 today.